# Linear gradient Firefox support

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, grunt-contrib-compass

When I make a linear gradient on [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), I take the scss code that looks like this:

```
@include background-image(linear-gradient(top,  #659adc 0%,#004ca2 100%));
```

which generates this css:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #659adc), color-stop(100%, #004ca2));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #659adc 0%, #004ca2 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #659adc 0%, #004ca2 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(top), color-stop(0%, #659adc), to(#004ca2));
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #659adc 0%, #004ca2 100%);
```

and none of these work with Firefox.
So i do a tweak and I add something I know works in Firefox:

```
@include background-image(linear-gradient(to bottom,  #659adc 0%,#004ca2 100%)); //notice the 'to bottom'
```

And now this is the generated css:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, to bottom, to top, color-stop(0%, #659adc), color-stop(100%, #004ca2));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #659adc 0%, #004ca2 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #659adc 0%, #004ca2 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#659adc), to(#004ca2));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #659adc 0%, #004ca2 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #659adc 0%, #004ca2 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #659adc 0%, #004ca2 100%);
```

which renders fine in Firefox, but compass task cries with this error:

> Cannot determine the opposite position of: to

Thoughts? How do you do a cross browser scss linear gradient?

Comment: Do you have the newest version of Compass?

Comment: @cimmanon, it's 0.12.3

Comment: That's not the newest version.  You need 1.0

Comment: This doesn't answer you question, but it's worth noting that simply using: `background-image: linear-gradient(#659adc, #004ca2)` should work fine, as gradients default top to bottom.

Comment: @cimmanon, it works, put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install the compass version ~1.0.0

To check the current version of compass you are using, type:

`$ compass version`

I updated my compass by uninstalling the current version and installing the latest version.

`$ gem uninstall compass
$ gem install compass`

**OR**

if you don't want to update you can simple use it without gradient direction.

`background-image: linear-gradient(#659adc, #004ca2)`